# Android Firebase "UserProfileChangeRequest" is working, but not after user sign out and sign in again

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I'm trying learn Android Firebase. When I program a code of Register user, it work successfully. But when I called "userProfileChangeRequest" method
to change username OR profile picture uri  it is work successfully, but new data isn't view to user before he log out and sign in again.

Why? What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
private void getUriPicture() {

     if(uriImage == null){
            //user didn't select profile picture
          return;
        }
        else if(!App.isOnline(this)) {
             Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.checkInternetConnection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
         }else{
         mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

         //upload picture to get Path
         Log.e(TAG,"test3");
            StorageReference path = mStorage.child("ProfilePicture").child(uriImage.getLastPathSegment()
                    + "_"
                    + App.randomNumber()
                    + "_"
                    + App.randomNumber());

         Log.e(TAG,"test4"+path);
            path.putFile(uriImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Upload success");
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl= taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    //Preview profile picture before set it to user
                    Picasso.with(Setting.this).load(downloadUrl).into(profilePicture);
                    setUserProfilePicture(downloadUrl);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    TF=false;
                    Toast.makeText(Setting.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }



    }


private void setUserProfilePicture(Uri downloadUrl) {

        //mProgress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.updateProfile));

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null) {
            Log.e(TAG,"test6");
            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setPhotoUri(downloadUrl)
                    .build();
            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Update Profile Successful");
                                Toast.makeText(Setting.this, getResources().getString(R.string.updateSuccessful), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Update Failure");
                    Toast.makeText(Setting.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to update the user image in UI inside onCompleteListener ? As there are no view update actions done after you UserProfileChangeRequest.

Comment: thanks for answer ...
but when i call "user.getPhotoUrl" Or "user.getDisplayName"
retrieved to me an old data 
when i re-signin the data is refresh